# Combo Box For ASP Page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, combobox

I'm in a bind and would really appreciate if someone helped out. I am trying to use a combo box in my asp page but all the ones that I found out use ajax are there any alternatives?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Note the `asp` tag is aliased to `asp-classic` but I suspect you are using `asp.net`?

Answer (score 1):

How about just using a HTML [`<select>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_select.asp) tag in your classic asp code?

Answer (score 0):

use ASP.NET DropDownList Control like this
`$`
`$`list item 1
`$`

Answer (score 0):

This is not quit a combo box...

The ASP is two sets of controls:
1: textbox and button
2: dropdown list and button

The button click events hide(self) and show(other).

```
        <div class="control-group">
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" class="control-label" runat="server" Text="Company"> </asp:Label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 ">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" class="control-label" runat="server" 
                        CssClass="form-control btn-group"
                        Width="240px"
                        AutoCompleteType="Disabled">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCompanySearch"
                        runat="server"
                        CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                        ToolTip="Company dropdown list" OnClick="btnCompanySearch_Click">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompanyName" runat="server"
                        CssClass="form-control btn-group"
                        Width="240px"
                        AutoPostBack="true" Visible="false"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCompanyText"
                        runat="server"
                        CssClass=" btn btn-primary"
                        Visible="false"
                        ToolTip="Enter company manually" OnClick="btnCompanyText_Click">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-font"></span>
                    </asp:LinkButton>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the code behind...

```
protected void ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtCompanyName.Text = ddlCompanyName.SelectedValue == "-1" ? string.Empty: ddlCompanyName.SelectedValue; 
    btnCompanyText_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
protected void btnCompanySearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Search(false);
    ddlCompanyName.Focus();
}
protected void btnCompanyText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Search(true);
    txtCompanyName.Focus();
}
private void Search(bool bVal)
{
    txtCompanyName.Visible = bVal;
    btnCompanySearch.Visible = bVal;
    btnCompanyText.Visible = !bVal;
    ddlCompanyName.Visible = !bVal;
}
```